# Get week of month C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, week-number

I want to find a date are now on week number with c# desktop Application.

I've been looking on google, but none that fit my needs.

How do I get a week in a month as the example below?

Example:

I want January 6, 2014 = the first week of January

January 30, 2014 = fourth `week` of January

but 1 February 2014 = week 4 in January

and 3 February 2014 was the first week in February

Comment: What is the first day of week? And what is the week number of January 1, 2014?

Comment: So your definition is "week 1 is from the first Monday occurring in the month until the subsequent Sunday"?

Comment: First google result that you could get: http://www.geekpedia.com/code72_Get-the-week-number-of-a-given-date.html

Comment: If you can dodge doing this, do so. Guaranteed to furrow brows everywhere this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is the method:

```
static int GetWeekNumberOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    date = date.Date;
    DateTime firstMonthDay = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    DateTime firstMonthMonday = firstMonthDay.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday + 7 - firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    if (firstMonthMonday > date)
    {
        firstMonthDay = firstMonthDay.AddMonths(-1);
        firstMonthMonday = firstMonthDay.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday + 7 - firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    }
    return (date - firstMonthMonday).Days / 7 + 1;
}
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetWeekNumberOfMonth(new DateTime(2014, 1, 6)));  // 1
Console.WriteLine(GetWeekNumberOfMonth(new DateTime(2014, 1, 30))); // 4
Console.WriteLine(GetWeekNumberOfMonth(new DateTime(2014, 2, 1)));  // 4
Console.WriteLine(GetWeekNumberOfMonth(new DateTime(2014, 2, 3)));  // 1
```

Comment: Absolute, this is the code what i want. Thank you very much @Ulugbek

Comment: This does not working for 21 March 2021

Comment: The code returns 4 for then following date:
Console.WriteLine(GetWeekNumberOfMonth(new  DateTime(2022,4,1)));

Comment: @MahmoodAbolfathzadeh the 4th week for 2022.04.01 is correct according to description provided by TS (one of samples is that 2022.02.01 is a 4th week of January).
March 1st week - 2022.03.07-2022.03.13
March 2nd week - 2022.03.14-2022.03.20
March 3rd week - 2022.03.21-2022.03.27
March 4th week - 2022.03.28-2022.04.03
So April 1st falls into 4th week of March.

Answer (score 4):

```
  public static int GetWeekNumber(DateTime dt)
  {
          CultureInfo curr= CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
          int week = curr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
          return week;
  }
```

Comment: He wants the week number of month, not of year.

Comment: Interesting piece of code, but this will return the week of -year-, not month. Also, beware of "FirstFourDayWeek" which may give unattended result.

Comment: the result is 16 if i use datetime.now, i want like my example get week on month.
I want January 6, 2014 = the first week of January.

January 30, 2014 = fourth week of January.

but 1 February 2014 = week 4 in January.

and 3 February 2014 was the first week in February.

Comment: @Enkhay Yea, got your question wrong, may be you can add some code to return the week of the month, probably will get downvotes now

Comment: Dim WeekNumber As Integer = GetWeekNumber(MyDate) - GetWeekNumber(LastDayLastMonth)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
public static int GetWeekOfMonth(DateTime date)  
{  
    DateTime beginningOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);  

    while (date.Date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek != CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)  
        date = date.AddDays(1);  

    return (int)Math.Truncate((double)date.Subtract(beginningOfMonth).TotalDays  / 7f) + 1;  
}
```

Its authored by David M Morton on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bf504bba-85cb-492d-a8f7-4ccabdf882cb/get-week-number-for-month

Comment: This code calculates the number of weeks regardless of the date of the first was on Monday or not. 
What I want is the first Monday of each month is the first week of the month. 
For example, if January 1, not on Monday, meaning January 1, including last week in the previous month.